# trying to understand .html( function(index, oldhtml) ) in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li class="specia">item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( 'li' ).html(function( index, oldHtml ) {
  return oldHtml + '!!!'
});
</script>
```

Question:

For this line: `function( index, oldHtml ),` I know `oldHtml` means the html value of `li`, but what does `index` mean here? and inside the function we did not use `index`, I checked the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml, but still did not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `index` means the position of the `li`-element.
Guess you have one `ul` containing five `li` elements, so `$('li')...` will match all five elements. The `index` tells you which element is selected. An example: let's say you will have the second `li` element in another color, so you can do like this:

```
$('li').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    if (index == 2) {
        jQuery(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple example would show you want it's doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqjg3/ generates:

```
#0 item 1!!!
#1 item 2!!!
#2 item 3!!!
```

The overload you're referring to is implicitly looping through the selected elements, though to be fair it doesn't seem like the API explains that very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

index is basically used to get the sibling number. Suppose there are 4

tags.

```
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Now you wanna change the 3rd node without traversing. In that case u will use the index.

```
$('li').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    if (index == 3) {
        $(this).text("modified third");
    }
});
```